# How can you initialize workers with doSMP?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there a way to initialize a doSMP cluster similar to `clusterEvalQ` and `clusterExport` in the snow package?  For example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1
z <- rnorm(10)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(2)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(quantmod))
clusterExport(cl, list("x","y","z"))
clusterEvalQ(cl, ls())
clusterEvalQ(cl, search())
```

There is an `initEnvir` option to doSMP, but `?doSMP` says

> ```
>  ‘initEnvir’ is a function to be executed by each worker before any
>  tasks are executed associated with a foreach.  Its purpose is to
>  initialize the execution environment, or the worker in general.
>  It is only executed by a worker if that worker executes at least
>  one task associated with the foreach.
> ```

Each worker needs a copy of several large objects in order to run the expression I send to `foreach`.  Additionally, I need to call `foreach` several hundred times, with identical versions of these large objects.  It would be inefficient to copy these objects for every call to `foreach`.

Even if there isn't a ready-made way to do this, I'd appreciate a kludge.

Comment: I thought there was access to the base environment, which would negate the need to copy.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just curious why are you implementing with doSMP instead of snow?  I've found snow to be more stable and portable.

Comment: @darckeen: I'm not _only_ implementing with doSMP.  I'm creating options for users to employ whatever foreach backend they choose, including doSMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `foreach` is `...` which transports the iterated objects for the evaluation of target expression. If you only need part of the object, then it may be more efficient to use `iter` to only pass portions of an object.

```
w <- startWorkers(workerCount = 4)
registerDoSMP(w)

foreach(x=iter(x),y=iter(y),z=iter(z) ) %dopar% (x*y*z)
```

The objects in the calling environment are still available:

```
foreach(1:10 ) %dopar% (x*y*z)  # Somewhat repetitious # 

zed <- 20:1
foreach(x=iter(x) ) %dopar% (x*zed)
```

Comment: Your last example is closest to what I'm trying to do, except `zed` is several hundred MB, and that example will be run several hundreds or thousands of times during a genetic algorithm optimization.  Copying `zed` for each of the several hundred/thousand `foreach` calls will be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(doSMP)
library(foreach)
w <- startWorkers(workerCount = 4)
registerDoSMP(w)
foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% sqrt(i)
```

Or you could use doSNOW and

```
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSNOW/doSNOW.pdf

Finally, there is doMC (not for windows)

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% sqrt(i)
```

All these techniques work before the new parallel package in 2.14, which I believe has done some unification of these techniques.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I need to copy objects to the workers before calling `foreach`.  I know about the other backends, but I need a solution for `doSMP` (see my comment).